# How do I center text vertically and horizontally inside CSS grid items?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

It's strange that CSS grid doesn't have properties that can do this easily (my codepen here: https://codepen.io/Chiz/pen/dydeZpz).

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container div {
  background-color: gray;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>Box 1</div>
  <div>Box 2</div>
  <div>Box 3</div>
  <div>Box 4</div>
</div>
```

If I use `align-self: center` and `justify-self: center` inside the `.container div` part, it shrinks the sizes of the boxes down to the size of the content.

Shouldn't CSS grid have properties such as grid-item-align:top center sort of thing?
I'm trying not to use 90s CSS hacks to do this cos' that would defeat the purpose of CSS grid.

With flexbox, it's far easier to align things where I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`flex` and `grid` works wonderfully together. Just apply your `flex`-positioning properties on the item you want.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: gray;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>Box 1</div>
  <div>Box 2</div>
  <div>Box 3</div>
  <div>Box 4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use flexbox on the items, while using grid on the container. Since flexbox is generally more used to align anything.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container div {
  background-color: gray;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>Box 1</div>
  <div>Box 2</div>
  <div>Box 3</div>
  <div>Box 4</div>
</div>
```